# Python log screen bug

Tags: python, function, authentication, button, tkinter

My `tkinter` log in screen app has a bug that is when i click the log in button it just show the error.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


login_page = Tk()
login_page.title("login_page")
login_page.geometry("250x110")

def check_pass():
    if username == name and userpass == password:
        print("this code works")
    else :
        messagebox.askretrycancel(title="Try again",message="Wrong password ")



# name and password entry
log_name = Entry(login_page)
log_name.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=15)
log_pass = Entry(login_page)
log_pass.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5)
name_label = Label(login_page, text="Name here:- ")
name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=15)
password_label = Label(login_page, text="Password:- ")
password_label.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)

# LOG IN BUTTON
login_btn = Button(login_page, text="LOG IN", command=check_pass)
login_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, ipadx=100, padx=5)

username = log_name.get()
userpass = log_pass.get()
name = "admin"
password= "admin"


mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the bug? and where is `login_page.mainloop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the `username` and the `password` variables are in the main block and when you run the code the entry boxes are empty(initially) which assigns `''` to the variables. So to overcome that you should assign the variables inside the function, where now the values of the filled entry box is only taken.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


login_page = Tk()
login_page.title("login_page")
login_page.geometry("250x110")


def check_pass():
    username = log_name.get()
    userpass = log_pass.get()
    if username == name and userpass == password:
        messagebox.showinfo('Successfull','Login successfull')
    else:
        choice = messagebox.askretrycancel("Try again","Wrong password ")
        if choice == True:
            pass
        else:
            login_page.destroy()

......
# ALL THE SAME LINES OF CODE TILL

name = "admin"
password = "admin"


login_page.mainloop()
```

Also since your using a messagebox like `askretrycancel`, you can do certain action based on the choice by the user. So here I have said if the user clicks on retry, then ask them to login again, or else close the application. You can change it to whatever you like(or even remove it too.)

And also it is recommended to say `login_page.mainloop()`, just so that tkinter isnt confused at any later steps.

Hope your "bug" is cleared and do let me know if any errors :D

Cheers