# How can I resolve the "invalid literal for int() with base 10" error when entering an integer in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the error that I am seeing:

> P = int(x1.get())
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

What can i do to read in integer from my entry widget?

```py
    from tkinter import *
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Investment Calculator')
    #use the entry widget to input data
    #use the width to increase the width, use fg and bg to change colour, use boarder to change boader 
    line
    P=IntVar()
    ROI=IntVar()
    months=IntVar()
    x1= Entry(root, width =30, fg= 'black', bg ='white', borderwidth=2)
    x2=Entry(root, width =30, fg= 'black', bg ='white', borderwidth=2)
    x3=Entry(root, width =30, fg= 'black', bg ='white', borderwidth=2)
    x1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    x2.grid(row=1, column=0)
    x3.grid(row=2, column=0)
    #to enter a default text into the entry widget, use the insert button
    P=int(x1.get())
    ROI=float(x2.get())
    months=int(x3.get())
    count = 0
    capital=0
    def mycalculator():
       for i in range(0,months,1):
          capital1 = P + P*ROI
          P1 = capital1
          interest = capital1-P
          P=P1
          count = count + i
          while count==months:
             break
    b = Button(root, text="Calculate", command=mycalculator)
    b.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    #to ensure it continues running in a loop, I have to create a loop

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The answer to your Q lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63358039/python-log-screen-bug/63358427#63358427)

Answer (score 1):

this is why you are using `.get()` in your code. you should use it in a function and create, for example, a button that gets the numbers when it is clicked. check this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Investment Calculator')
#use the entry widget to input data
#use the width to increase the width, use fg and bg to change colour, use boarder to change boader line

def click():
    P=int(x1.get())
    ROI=float(x2.get())
    months=int(x3.get())
    print(P, ROI, months) # for test

P=IntVar()
ROI=IntVar()
months=IntVar()
x1= Entry(root, width =30, fg= 'black', bg ='white', borderwidth=2)
x2=Entry(root, width =30, fg= 'black', bg ='white', borderwidth=2)
x3=Entry(root, width =30, fg= 'black', bg ='white', borderwidth=2)
x1.grid(row=0, column=0)
x2.grid(row=1, column=0)
x3.grid(row=2, column=0)
bt = Button(root, text="click", command= click)
bt.grid(row=3, column=0)
#to enter a default text into the entry widget, use the insert button

root.mainloop()
```

in this code, I have shown you how to define a function for your button. so when the button clicked, it will use the function to get the numbers in the type that you want.
[image]